# pino loses log entries on process.exit()

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, flush, pinojs

When my program shuts down via `process.exit()` (maybe also by some signal), [pino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino) loses some log entries because it is not properly flushing them.

Triggering a manual flush does not help.

I am using pino 6.2.0.

**How can I prevent log entries from getting lost?**

```js
const pino = require("pino");

const p = pino();

process.on("exit", () => {
    console.log("FLUSH");
    p.flush();
});

p.info("A"); // logged
p.info("B"); // NOT logged

process.exit(1);
```

**Back story:**
I was missing some dependencies in my NestJS module and configured NestJS to use my pino logger wrapper like this:

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    logger: new PinoLoggerService(),
});
```

NestJS was just exiting (using `process.exit()`) without telling me what was wrong.
Removing the `logger` option made NestJS print the offending module in all details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching the net yielded a comment on a GitHub issue [Pino 5.8.1 fails to flush log on process exit](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/issues/542#issuecomment-437528322) with a similar problem where [GitHub user brandondoran](https://github.com/brandondoran) pointed out the solution:

Use `pino.destination()` which will use synchronous writes unless you disable them, no explicit flushing needed.

Note that this will likely slow down your logging.

```js
const pino = require("pino");

const p = pino({}, pino.destination());

p.info("A"); // logged
p.info("B"); // logged as well

process.exit(1);
```

Comment: As well, have a look here: https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/HEAD/docs/asynchronous.md